# Cold-start problem in Real Time Bidding

Tags: reinforcement-learning, weight-initialization

I'm currently on the reading stage of the deployment of an RTB system. I've seen the problem of a cold start (having no initial guess of how to bid) in several papers, but I haven't really seen it be formally addressed. Could somebody point me to some recent literature on the topic, or briefly discuss how they've faced it? Thanks!